# How do I host a Plugin Repository based on git?

Tags: php, git, plugins

Users can extend our PHP application with plugins, and we would like to host all these plugins, but more than just hosting files we want to allow users to version their files with git. Finally too, we'd like for other people using these plugins to be able to review/rate the plugins.

Is there any such script/software out there that allows you to do this? Wordpress has some type of BBPress front-end that interacts with SVN for their wordpress.com/extend plugin website. In a nutshell its a git hosting platform combined with a front-end based on PHP... too much to ask for?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, decided to go with a PHP based Forge app called indefero: http://www.indefero.net/